# How do I fix this key error I keep getting?

Tags: python, pygame, keyerror

```
import math
import random
import pygame
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class cube(object):
    rows = 20
    w = 500
    def __init__(self,start,dirnx=1,dirny=0,color=(255,0,0)):
        self.pos = start
        self.dirnx = 1
        self.dirny = 0
        self.color = color

    def move(self, dirnx, dirny):
        self.dirnx = dirnx
        self.dirny = dirny
        self.pos = (self.pos[0] + self.dirnx, self.pos[1] + self.dirny)
    def draw(self, surface):
        dis = self.w // self.rows
        i = self.pos[0]
        j = self.pos[1]

        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (i*dis+1, j*dis+1, dis-2, dis-2))
        if eyes: 
            centre = dis//2
            radius = 3
            circleMiddle = (i*dis+centre-radius,j*dis+8)
            circleMiddle2 = (i*dis + dis -radius*2, j*dis+8)
            pygame.draw.circle(surface, (0,0,0), circleMiddle, radius)
            pygame.draw.circle(surface, (0,0,0), circleMiddle2, radius)

class snake(object):
    body = []
    turns = {}
    def __init__(self, color, pos):
        self.color = color
        self.head = cube(pos)
        self.body.append(self.head)
        self.dirnx = 0
        self.dirny = 1

    def move(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            for key in keys:
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    self.dirnx = -1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    self.dirnx = 1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = -1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = 1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

        for i, c in enumerate(self.body):
            p = c.pos[:]
            if p in self.turns:
                turn = self.turns[p]
                c.move(turn[0], turn[1])
            if i == len(self.body)-1:
                print(p, '-', self.turns)
                self.turns.pop(p)
            else:
                if c.dirnx == -1 and c.pos[0] <= 0: c.pos = (c.rows-1, c.pos[1])
                elif c.dirnx == 1 and c.pos[0] >= c.rows-1: c.pos = (0,c.pos[1])
                elif c.dirny == 1 and c.pos[1] >= c.rows-1: c.pos = (c.pos[0], 0)
                elif c.dirny == -1 and c.pos[1] <= 0: c.pos = (c.pos[0], c.rows-1)
                else: c.move(c.dirnx, c.dirny)

    def reset(self, pos):
        self.head = cube(pos)
        self.body = []
        self.body.append(self.head)
        self.turns = {}
        self.dirnx = 0
        self.dirny = 1

    def addCube(self):
        tail = self.body[-1]
        dx, dy = tail.dirnx, tail.dirny

        if dx == 1 and dy == 0:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0]-1, tail.pos[1])))
        elif dx == 1 and dy == 0:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0]+1, tail.pos[1])))
        elif dx == -1 and dy == 0:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0], tail.pos[1]-1)))
        elif dx == 0 and dy == -1:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0], tail.pos[1]+1)))

        self.body[-1].dirnx = dx
        self.body[-1].dirny = dy

    def draw(self, surface):
        for i, c in enumerate(self.body):
            if i == 0:
                c.draw(surface, True)
            else:
                c.draw(surface)

def drawGrid(w, rows,surface):
    sizeBtwn = w // rows

    x = 0
    y = 0 
    for l in range(rows):
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn

        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (x,0), (x,w))
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (0,y), (w,y))

def redrawWindow(surface):
    global rows, width, s, snack
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    s.draw(surface)
    snack.draw(surface)
    drawGrid(width, rows, surface)
    pygame.display.update()

def randomSnack(rows, item):

    positions = item.body

    while True:
        x = random.randrange(rows)
        y = random.randrange(rows)
        if len(list(filter(lambda z:z.pos == (x,y), positions))) > 0:
            continue
        else:
            break

    return (x,y)

def message_box(subject, content):
    root = tk.TK()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.withdraw()
    messagebox.showinfo(subject, content)
    try:
        root.destroy()
    except:
        pass

def main():
    global width, rows, s, snack
    width = 500 
    rows = 20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width,width))
    s = snake((255,0,0), (10,10))
    snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(0,255,0))
    flag = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)
        s.move()
        if s.body[0].pos == snack.pos:
            s.addCube()
            snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(0,255,0))
        for x in range(len(s.body)):
            if s.body[x].pos in list(map(lambda z:z.pos, s.body[x+1:])):
                print('Score: ', len(s.body))
                message_box('You Lost!', 'Play again...')
                s.reset((10,10))
                break

        redrawWindow(win)

    pass

main()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
     (10,10) - {}
     Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "snake.py" line 191, in <module>
           main()
        File "snake.py", line 176, in main
           s.move()
        File "snake.py", line 79, in move
           self.turns.pop(p)
     KeyError: (10, 10)
```

I Believe (10, 10) Refers to (x, y) I'm following a tutorial (an in depth description would help me understand how to fix this) I believe it maybe my tuple but I'm not sure how to fix it. I followed a tutorial on Youtube from TechWithTim. This is a snake program, but I'm unsure how or what this error means. The snake should turn and be placed in a grid, but even pygame refuses to start. It did start when testing, however after I made the snake move the program stopped working and gave me this error.

Comment: you didn't post the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the error is thrown from this code segment:

```
if i == len(self.body)-1:
    print(p, '-', self.turns)
    self.turns.pop(p)
```

According to the printout, the `self.turns` dictionary is empty, so there is nothing to pop from it. You will have to figure out why the dictionary is empty why it is not supposed to be.

Could it be that indentation is wrong? Maybe you only want to remove `p` from `turns` if the test `p in self.turns` was true?

Comment: P is c.pos[:] I assume this is the position of the cube. and the dictionary is set as empty just above this at the start of snake class. Do you mean to put a 0 instead of it being empty? Like what would I use to figure out why the dictionary is empty and why its not supposed to be?

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to single-step through your code with a debugger and trace what is actually happening and all is expected. Maybe also add some assertions to your code to make sure at each place things are as expected. I wouldn't know why the dict is empty while it is not supposed to be because I did not write your code and there are zero comments. So it is not obvious what the code does and what it is supposed to do. The best option probably is to really understand what this tutorial is doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will go through with a debugger and re-watch the tutorial to understand exactly what the error is. I thought it would be a learning lesson. Have a great day, thanks for the help!